# How to remove .php extention from address bar?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to remove .php from address bar. Actually my address bar is located this site http://localhost/product/login.php. But i want show that address bar look like this format http://localhost/product/login without the ".php" extention.

Comment: You can use `.htaccess` file [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1pbAV6AU99I)

Comment: i don't know about .htaccess file. can you please explain that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: From where can i get the .htaccess file?

Comment: Read this link  [link](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/)